# I want to create a table in html with respect to the no.of rows and no.of columns entered by user

Tags: php, html, css

I want to create a table in html with respect to the no.of rows and no.of columns entered by user..

Can Any one please help me by giving the code for it...

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: https://github.com/profburial/html-table-generator/tree/master/src/HtmlTableGenerator - PHP class to help you generate tables.

Comment: see this question bro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962968/how-do-i-create-tables-dynamically-from-user-input

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I propose you include a code snippet of what you have attempted; not only so we can help further, but also it will benefit your knowledge further.

I have quickly done some code, it is untested so I apologise if it does not work. The code below assumes that a form has been submitted and a variable has been set with the name of rows, and another will cols.

```
<?php
$rows = isset($_POST["rows"]) ? $_POST["rows"] : 0; // get the number of rows submitted
$cols = isset($_POST["cols"]) ? $_POST["cols"] : 0; // get the number of cols submitted
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <table>
    <?php
    // begin to create the table - rows first
    for ($row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++) { ?>
        <tr>
        <?php for ($col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++) { ?>
            <td></td>
        <?php } // end cols for loop ?>
        </tr>
    <?php } // end rows for loop ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope I have understood the question correctly and this answer proves helpful.